# Non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java3

Tags: android, android-ndk, opencv3.0

In the `android.mk` file I want to include the `OpenCV3` library. so the file looks like this:

**android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES  := D:\path to\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include
include D:\path to\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := file1.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += file2.cpp

OPENGLES_LIB := -lGLESv1_CM
OPENGLES_DEF := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But when I build the project, I got this warning message:

```
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:MyLib: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java3    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Do you use OpenCV from Java or from C++?

Comment: I am using the OpenCV native in C++ files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only use OpenCV from your C++ code, you don't need this libopencv_java.so. To indicate this, add

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE=STATIC
```

Before including OpenCV.mk.

Some explanations can be found at [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/913/how-the-libopencv_javaso-is-copy-to-the-apk-when-it-is-used-the-static-lib-type/).

Answer (score 2):

`Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the current module`

Depending on which version you have (static/dylibs), change your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` to either `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` or `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`

[Android.mk](http://android.mk/) is a good reference to variables in the Android makefile